# Задачи Java и решение

Tags: java

Данный вопрос был закрыт из-за неполной информации.

Comment: встроенные приложения это наверное для микроконтроллеров, что-то типа Java SE Embedded, серверные приложения - это я допускаю например апи, которое будет обращаться в бд, а веб приложение это то что будет обращаться к апи которое в свою очередь стучится в бд, но я могу ошибаться, если что ниже меня исправят)

Answer (score 1):

Встраиваемые -- это для всяких контроллеров, не обязательно микро и не обязательно на `embedded`. Это могут быть, например мозги для робота, или для беспилотника (как авиа, так и авто), или для большого адронного коллайдера.

Серверные -- это когда клиентские приложения могут обращаться к серверу за информацией или за услугами, например SQL-серверы или веб-сервисы. Человек напрямую с сервером не общается в таком случае, общается через специальные клиентские приложения, и вообще структура может быть сложной, многоуровневой. Выдача сервера в таком случае -- не обязательно `HTML`, это может быть `XML`, `JSON` и вообще что угодно, и общение c сервером не обязательно по `HTTP`.

Веб-приложения -- это то, что выдает `HTML`-страницы, пригодные для просмотра человеком через браузер, например `stackoverflow` или `facebook`. Также сюда входят всякие корпоративные приложения для внутренних целей, типа документооборот, управление проектами, CRM и т. п., если с ними работают через браузер, без специальных клиентских программ.

Но вся эта терминология не очень четкая и границы не очень чёткие, например, большинство развитых веб-приложений имеют `API` для мобильных приложений и всяких специализированных программ, типа браузерных плагинов, и в этом смысле их можно назвать и серверными приложениями. К тому-же разные люди могут понимать эти термины по-разному.